# javadoc @global or @memberAttribute

Tags: java, android, javadoc

Javadoc is friendly easy-to-self-document utility.  It has many straight forward tags  such as: `@param` `@return`  `@throws`.  However, I don't see a way to document access to "global" or "member attribute" variables.

I've looked through SO, $search, some of the java/oracle docs on Javadoc ([example1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) , [example2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html)).

While it is typically recommended to pass manipulated variables via function parameters, there are valid design occasions where a function must either access or modify variables beyond its local scope (ex: "global" or "member attribute" variables).  I'm trying to find the best way to document this sort of access.

Basic code example:

```
<!-- language: lang-java  -->
/**
 * Update various UI widgets text and state.
 * @global mState is read to identify current state.
 */
private void updateWidgetsLook() {
  // stuff...   
}
```

thx - android tag is because that's the environment I'm working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @link tag for such purposes, eg:

```
<!-- language: lang-java  -->
/**
 * Update various UI widgets text and state.
 * {@link #mState} is read to identify current state.
 */
private void updateWidgetsLook() {
  // stuff...   
}
```

In the above example, mstate must reside in the current class. If it resides in a different class then it can be accessed like: {@link ResidingClass#mState}.